# Is there any way I can control a supernight IP65 32ft rgb lighting strip with my raspberry pi?

Tags: usb

I am using the SUPERNIGHT DC24V 10M 5050 FLEXIBLE RGB LED STRIP LIGHT KIT, 32.8FT LED TAPE, 300 UNITS 5050 LEDS, IP65 NON-WATERPROOF LED LIGHT STRIPS + 24V 5A POWER ADAPTER + 44KEY IR REMOTE CONTROLLER

Lighting strips that are rgb. I've seen some tutorials but not many that apply to this certain kit. Thank you!

Comment: Using capital letters is considered screaming. And the way to control IR in linux is `lirc`.

Comment: http://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/

Comment: I copied and pasted the name and it was caps. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I would check the voltage one the tutorial link posted. It is for a 12v strip. Yours says 24v? Raspberry pi 5v.  Seems a bit inefficient to me.